# Cronbach alpha ltm or psych packages what's the difference?

Tags: r, statistics, alphanumeric, psych

Recently, he's been working on survey data. I want to use alpha cronach but I wonder which packages is better and what are the differences between ltm and psych packag. The data comes from surveys regarding the assessment of the quality of life.

[ltm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCDaR.png)
[psych](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YXAa.png)

Answer (score 0):

LTM
[image]
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ltm/ltm.pdf

PSYCH
[image]

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf
It took me a 1 minute of google search to find the documentation online for both packages, then ctrl+f and find the way each compute the Cronbach alpha...